# Magento2 : After enabled the cache home page condition not working on the footer?

Tags: magento2.3

```
<?php
$objectManagerCms = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManagerCms->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');
if($cmsPage->getIdentifier() == "home"){ ?>
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('home_remains_content')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php  } ?>
```

I am using the above code on the footer. and the added block is showing on all pages instead of the home page.

Meant on the list and detail page $cmsPage->getIdentifier() is showing Identifier "home" .if after cache refreshed first we are review home page.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears when the cache is on because the footer is cached the same for all pages.
You either move it outside the footer block, but this might not be easy if you need it in a specific case.
Or you can create different cache for the homepage.

For this you can create an `after` plugin on the `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer::getCacheKeyInfo` method.
Here is how you can create a plugin: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

and your plugin class can look like this:

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Html;

class FooterPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetCacheKeyInfo(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer $subject,
        array $result
    ) {
        $handle = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        $homeHandle = 'cms_index_index';
        $result[] = ($handle === $homeHandle);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

CLear the cache and you should now have 2 cache versions for the footer. One for homepage and one for the rest of the pages.

Bonus: Don't use Object manager in templates. Use the approach [Amit Bera showed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/314756/146) to get your content into the page.

(i didn't test the code so watch out for typos).

Comment: Good idea marius.I will use this logic in future

Answer (score 0):

If you using object manage in this way then you always get the issue at cache.

Best way to add cms block using the layout.

Create `cms_index_index.xml` at your theme if it not exits

Than add below code at that layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="{NameInLayout}">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home.remains.content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home_remains_content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

After on phtml  call where `if($cmsPage->getIdentifier() == "home"){ ?>` write the code. At there add below code

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('home.remains.content');?>
```